# fexecve not functioning as expected

Tags: c, execve

so as I understand `fexecve` is like `execve` except that it takes a file descriptor instead of a path.
So here's my code that isn't working :/

```c
#define _DEFAULT_SOURCE
#include <stdio.h>
#include <fcntl.h>
#include <sys/stat.h>

int main() {
    int fd = open("test", O_RDONLY);
    printf("File : %d\n", fd)
    fexecve(fd, NULL, NULL);
}
```

and here's `test`:

```c
#include <stdlib.h>

int main() {
    system("mkdir pls");
}
```

any idea?

Comment: `test` looks like c source code. `fexecve` expects the file descriptor to be opened on an executable file.

Comment: yea I said `test.c` which is the source file of `test` (a compiled version duh)

Comment: Where did you say `test.c`?  Are you intending to be rude?

Comment: no sorry, but I thought it'd be obvious that it's the source file of that binary

Comment: It's obvious that fexecve will fail if you pass NULL as either of the 2nd or 3rd arguments, so...

Comment: so what should I pass?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/219297/discussion-between-spooky-sec-and-william-pursell).

Answer (score 2):

As stated in the documentation:

```
  Errors are as for execve(2), with the following additions:

  EINVAL fd is not a valid file descriptor, or argv is NULL, or envp is NULL.
```

You can't pass NULL for the parameters.  Instead, try something like:

```
int
main(void) 
{
    int fd = open("test", O_RDONLY);
    char *env[] = { NULL };
    char *argv[] = { "test", NULL };
    fexecve(fd, argv, env);
    perror("fexecve");
    return EXIT_FAILURE;
}
```

Comment: it still gives an `invalid argument`

Comment: It works for me, after adding the necessary `#include`s.  Maybe test the return value of `open` to make sure it succeeded, in case your file `test` is not where you think it is?